# Request failed with code 409 Data flow and goole Big query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

> We are reading from GBQ to perform data comparisons with other data source and using Google data flow to do this computation. We are getting below error during the data flow job execution and GBQ read step is not returning any data. When we manually executed same the query, it's returning the data in GBQ Web Console.I tried few blogs but couldn't find any solution. I'm using 2.15 beam version.

```
PCollection<KV<String, DTO.class>> gbqDtoDetails = pipeline
        .apply("read-DTO-from-gbq", BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
        .fromQuery(String.format(SQL_QUERY, Integer.parseInt(opts.getNbr())))
            .withoutValidation().usingStandardSql())
        .apply("Map Table row to DTO", ParDo.of(new TableRowToDTOMapperFn()))
        .setCoder(KvCoder
            .of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), SerializableCoder.of(DTO.class)));
```

1. Apache beam version - 2.15.
2. **Error in data flow logs**
   2020-07-30 (17:08:02) Request failed with code 409, performed 0 retries due to IOExceptions, performed 0 retries due to
   un...Request
   failed with code 409, performed 0 retries due to IOExceptions,
   performed 0 retries due to unsuccessful status codes, HTTP framework
   says request can be retried, (caller responsible for retrying):
   [https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{projectId}/jobs](https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/%7BprojectId%7D/jobs).
   timestamp   2020-07-30T21:08:02.240Z
   logger  org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.RetryHttpRequestInitializer
   severity     WARNING worker  step
   **read-upc-loc-price-gbq/Read(BigQueryQuerySource)** thread  25

Comment: Hi there, can you please post your code and configuration?

Comment: Hi @cubez. - Updated code snippet in the description.

Comment: Looks like BigQuery 409 means that you are trying to create a resource (job, dataset, table) that already exists. Can you double check your config that you are using unique names? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages

Comment: @cubez - Adding "withTemplateCompatibility" has helped me. The job run time has increased but no longer seen this error from GBQ.

Comment: Just to add to the above comment by @Vali7394 , this is true if you are using BigQueryIO. Here is the specific section : https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#pipeline-io-and-runtime-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You should add `withTemplateCompatibility` to `BigQueryIO.readTableRows()`

Something like:

```
BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
         .fromQuery("SELECT ...")
         .withoutValidation()
         .withTemplateCompatibility()
         .usingStandardSql();
```